# How can I read/write from a plain text in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I don't know much about JS, I'm new in this world, I know about HTML and CSS but this time I was asked to make an aplication where I have to receive data from a plain text to my formulary using JS.

Here's my Plain Text data.txt:

```
Interfaces: test1,
IP: 192.168.1.1,
Mask : test,
Gateway : test,
DNS 1: test,
DNS 2: test,
Broadcast: test
```

Here's my Div:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-panel">
            <h4><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Formulario </h4>
            <hr />
            <form method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 col-sm-3 control-label">Interfaces:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                    </div>      
                </div>  
                 <div class="form-group ">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 col-sm-3 control-label">IP: </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control"
                    </div>
                </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 col-sm-3 control-label">Mask : </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 col-sm-3 control-label"> Gateway : </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 col-sm-3 control-label">DNS 1 : </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 col-sm-3 control-label">DNS 2 : </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 col-sm-3 control-label">Broadcast : </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br><br>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" name="Save" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" " title="Save"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Save</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

That's the script I got from you guys, because I was looking for code to do it and that's what I got.

The point is the data that contains "data.tx" should be on my formulary and if I modify any field there and I hit "save" button it has to write on my plain text as well.

Is there a way to make it work? thanks!

Entire code bellow.

```js
var mytext;
var connection = new XMLHttpRequest();
connection.open('GET', '/data.txt');
connection.onreadystatechange = function() {
mytext=connection.responseText;
}
connection.send();
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-panel">
                <h4><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Formulario </h4>
                <hr />
    <form method="post">
     <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 col-sm-3 control-label">Interfaces:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                       </div>      
     </div> 
      <div class="form-group ">
      <label class="col-sm-3 col-sm-3 control-label">IP: </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
       <input type="text" class="form-control"
      </div>
                    </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 col-sm-3 control-label">Mask : </label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
                         <input type="text" class="form-control" 
      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 col-sm-3 control-label"> Gateway : </label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
                         <input type="text" class="form-control" 
      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 col-sm-3 control-label">DNS 1 : </label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
                         <input type="text" class="form-control" 
      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 col-sm-3 control-label">DNS 2 : </label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
                         <input type="text" class="form-control" 
      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 col-sm-3 control-label">Broadcast : </label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
                         <input type="text" class="form-control" 
      </div>
                    </div>
     <br><br>
     <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" name="Save" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" " title="Save"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Save</button>
     </div>
    </form>
   </div>
 
</div>
```

Comment: You're missing some critical checks in your `onreadystatechange` event handler, find a tutorial, any tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know i a more efficient solution exists, but below code is working.

Here is how I achieved it, using jQuery [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Load the file in an hidden div element.
    $("#hiddenFileLoad").load("data.txt", function(){
        // Callback executes when content is loaded

        // Place the content in a var
        var loadedText = $("#hiddenFileLoad").text();
        console.log("loadedText:\n\n"+loadedText);

        // Split into an array
        var loadedTextSplitted = loadedText.split(",");

        // Remove the label part for each
        for (i=0;i<loadedTextSplitted.length;i++){
            temp = loadedTextSplitted[i].split(": ");
            loadedTextSplitted[i] = temp[1];
        }

        // Place each info in the HTML form
        $(".form-panel").find("input").each(function(index){
            $(this).val( loadedTextSplitted[index] );
        });

    }); // End of .load callback
});
```

I used and hidden `div`, in order to load the .txt file content, which I gave the "hiddenFileLoad" `id`.

I made absolutely no change to your HTML (except the hidden div add) and I used your txt file content.

I assume you know how to save to file...
I didn't make the save button to work.

[Here is a **live example**](https://www.bessetteweb.com/SO/39810153/txt-file-read-via-jQuery.html) on my server.

Comment: Thanks! All I need is find out how to make the buttom work for write on the text file! thanks!